# Which certificate files should I share?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

I have used acme.sh (highly recommended) for generating certificates. I have got several files here in which I do not understand which should I share and which should I hold back.

These are the files that I have:
ca.cer
example.com.cer
example.com.csr
example.com.key
fullchain.cer

example.com.conf
example.com.csr.conf

uwsgi requires such a command

```
uwsgi --master --https 0.0.0.0:8443,foobar.crt,foobar.key
```

These files all look similar to each other, ofc they are keys.
My question is, what are the contents of each of these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not understand which should I share and which should I hold back.

The domain (ex. `example.com`) certificate and key files are often the two files a server is required to know about (e.g. Nginx or Apache on Windows). Some software may use the `fullchain` certificate, either in conjunction with the domain certificate (e.g. [Apache on Linux](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh)) or in place of it (apparently `uwsgi`), but this depends on the software itself.

For `uwsgi` specifically, based on this [Let's Encrypt forum post](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/using-private-key-for-a-standalone-uwsgi-instance/111420), it seems likely the `fullchain` certificate and `example.com` key are needed to start the example `uwsgi` server with SSL support (so any `fullchain` certificate would take the place of `foobar.crt` in your example).

---

*Please note that the [official acme.sh GitHub account](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh) states "DO NOT use the certs files in `~/.acme.sh/` folder, they are for internal use only, the folder structure may change in the future."*

---

> What are the contents of each of these files?

- The domain certificate file is typically sent to clients that connect to the server and key file is kept on the server itself. These files are used as part of the process for establishing secure communications between a client and server.
- `example.com.csr` is a [certificate signing request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) (CSR), an intermediate file that is sent to a [certificate authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) (CA) such as Let's Encrypt that allows the CA to issue a final set of certificates to a you.
- The `fullchain` file is a signed domain certificate (if I am not mistaken) concatenated with one or more intermediate certificates that make up the issuing certificate authority (CA) chain. This [digicert article on how certificate chains work](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO16297.html) may be of some interest regarding intermediate CA certificates and why they are important.

Regarding the remaining items, while I am not familiar with `acme.sh`, my guess would be that `CA.cer` is the intermediate CA certificate mentioned above. It would also seem likely that `example.com.conf` and `example.com.csr.conf` are configuration files for `acme.sh` for the given domain. But again, that is a guess.

However, you should be able to verify these assumptions by simply opening the relevant files in a standard text editor (i.e. by comparing `example.com.cer`, `ca.cer` and `fullchain.cer` and simply looking at the relevant `.conf` files).